# How to return array from Filenamefilter in java

Tags: java

Filename filter function is

```
Filterfilter = new FilenameFilter() {
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
return name.equals(""+abc.get(i));
} 
};
```

I have a folder with more than 1000 bmp files and if i want to return an array through filenamefilter then how is it possible ??

Comment: what is exactly your problem ? returning names ? you can return array, vector, list, ...1000 is not so big.

Comment: My prb is suppose i am havinf an arraylist abc["one.bmp","two.bmp","three.bmp"] then i want to search these three names in a folder and rename it

Comment: @bjk I think you do not want to return an array, but use an array as an argument to find files, or am I right?

Comment: The question lacks a clear _tried this, expected this, got that_ format (it's not clear where the problem actually is). All over it the code is not formatted. Please add a piece of example code that outlines what you want to archieve. Temporarily downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible

```
    FilenameFilter filenameFilter = new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
            if (filename.endsWith(".abc")) {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    };
    File dir = new File("Your folder path");

    File[] filterFiles = dir.listFiles(filenameFilter);
```

Comment: It is not ending with abc its ending with bmp and my folder has all bmp files only

Comment: just replace abc with your bmp extension

Comment: I think ur not understanding ... my folder consist of all bmp files and so this filter is of no use

Comment: Please consider adding some description what the TO was doing wrong and consider adding references/documentation links.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this. It will return all the bmp files.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        File f = new File(args[0]);
        if(f.isDirectory()){
            File name[] = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
                {
                    public boolean accept(File path, String name)
                        {
                            File f1 = new File(path,name);
                            return name.endsWith(".bmp");
                        }
                });
            for(File n : name)
                System.out.println(n.getName());
        }
    }
}
```